# RequireJS not loading a file or module named "module.js"

Tags: requirejs

I just started using RequireJS. I tried a simple code but one way works but the other doesn't.

folder "script" has "main.js", "module.js", "require.js"

`<script data-main="script/main.js" src="script/require.js"></script>`

in main.js

```
requirejs( ['module'], function( mod ) {
    mod.sayHello();
} );
```

in module.js:

```
define( {
    name : "value",
    sayHello : function() {
        alert( "Hello" );
    },
    sayBye : function() {
        alert( "Bye" );
    }
} );
```

I expect baseUrl to be "script" as mentioned in here:

http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#jsfiles

> The baseUrl is normally set to the same directory as the script used in a data-main attribute for the top level script to load for a page.

So, I thought there would be no problem, but doesn't mod.sayHello() nor sayBye() and console.log( mod.name ) = undefined.

I tried `console.log( mod )` and it prints something like this:

`Object {id: "_@r6", uri: "script/_@r6.js", exports: Object}`

When I use ["script/module.js"] instead of ["module"], `console.log( mod )` prints like the following:

```
Object {name: "value"}
name: "value"
sayBye: ()
sayHello: ()
__proto__: Object
```

and mod.sayHello(), mod.sayBye(), mod.name all works.

including the following in the beginning of main.js is the same:

```
requirejs.config( {
    baseUrl: "script"
} );
```

What am I doing wrong... Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a different name than `module` for your module. For one thing, it is a terribly uninformative name, but the module named `module` is a special module for RequireJS. It is a module that gives information about the module you are currently in. For instance if `foo.js` contains this code:

```
define(['module'], function (module) {
    console.log(module.id);
});
```

and this file is loaded when you request the module named `foo`, then `console.log` will show `"foo"` on the console.

The documentation does not highlight the existence of `module` but it talks about it when explaining what the configuration option [`config`](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-moduleconfig) does. Because you get to access the config of your module through `module.config()`.

The reason requiring `"script/module.js"` works is because when you do this you require a module named `script/module.js` rather than `module`.

Comment: oh...I just discovered that a file named "test.js" works ( on different computer ). So that could be the reason for my code working but not working at the same time. So, there already exists 'module', so it doesn't give me "Script error ... whatever file name is not found". I should've tried it with the "module.js" in other folder. This is something I never expected. I read the documentation only up to 1.3 then tried myself. Thanks for such a great info.

Answer (score 0):

I continued reading the documentation:

http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html

and it led to a github that has information about this:

https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Differences-between-the-simplified-CommonJS-wrapper-and-standard-AMD-define#magic

It turns out that "module" is a kind of "magic modules" along as "require", "export".

And "module" ... :

> gives you information about the module ID and location of the current module

https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Differences-between-the-simplified-CommonJS-wrapper-and-standard-AMD-define#module